# How to localize content coming from third party libraries in Angular

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I am using multiple libraries in my angular application. I want to understand how I can localize contents coming from these libraries or is there a way to load their translation files in the application? I want to load the library translation files as and when used. Want to understand ways to achieve this using ngx-translate as well as angular/i18n.

Comment: It depends on the library. if the library does not offer an interface to provide custom text strings, it's not easily possible. You could maybe hack something around and overwrite the output.

Comment: How to achieve it in ngx-translate? Does it provide an interface to achieve this?

Comment: How to achieve what exactly?

Comment: I have multiple libraries in my project. Each comes with their respective translation files. I want the translation files of a particular library to be loaded when it is in use.

Comment: This depends on the library, as stated on my comment above. There's no standardised way on how to handle translations in Angular.